# pexpect get application information

Tags: python, python-3.6, pexpect

I am using pexpect to run nano from the linux host, I am trying to find a way to get information back from pexpect so I can rebuild nano (or vi or any terminal application) somewhere else.

So something like:

```
p = pexpect.spawn('/bin/bash')
p.sendline('nano cheese')
#Get the tty information for the nano/vi/whatever UI#
```

I essentially want to forward the information (the information being the applications UI) without directly interacting with it, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the way to deal with this is to .interact(), which puts the subprocess in the current process. However, it sounds like you don't want to interact, but want to control the subprocess from the parent.

Something like this should work:

```
import pexpect

p = pexpect.spawn('nano cheese')
output = []
while p.isalive():
    output.append(p.read_nonblocking(100000))
    #Conditionals about what is in output could be put here. 
    #You can also tell pexpect to block until it finds specific strings, with .expect()
    p.sendline(input().encode())
```

Trying to follow what should be typed in "nano", I think you want to do something like this:

```
y       #answer yes to first question
^X      #exit nano
n       #no, don't save
<enter> #anything sent should end the process here.
```

This assumes "nano" did not ask something unexpected, like there was already a file or something, etc. You can use p.expect to initiate certain actions based on strings that show up in the output. Print output to see what "nano" is sending you.

```
print(output)
```

Comment: Yes thats is what I want, im going to try this code out and mess with it a bit. Though more specifically I am trying to PIPE applications over websockets, though I lose all the UI when the process switches into nano (which you would expect) 

I am essentially trying to have a interactive shell [e.g. pty.spawn("/bin/bash")] over websockets, I can run long scripts in real time and maintain my session but am stuck at implementing the functionality to allow for things like nano and vi etc.

Comment: this already looks so good, I might have to make you my new BFF

Comment: lol, thanks, glad I could help. The power is really in the pexpect module though, it handles a lot of the tedious difficulties in doing this manually.

Comment: is there anyway to tell that i have switched from bash to nano in a simple way? I can obviously see some identifiers in the response but I want to make something generic - my application in theory wont know the difference between `ls -la` and `nano cheese` other than maybe a simple check on tty change

Comment: I don't think so. Unless you are the one tracking what you send to the subprocess or analyzing the output. What you send is not guaranteed to produce another sub-subprocess, it could fail.